# Client side routing (using BrowserRouter) with dynamic server in react does not work proprely

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building a react app, using client side routing (BrowserRouter).
Server side is written in python Flask (dynamic server).
For some reason, refreshing some of the pages / accesssing routes does not work properly, return only the index.html file but does not nevigate to the window.location.href URL.

Based on: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment

> If you use routers that use the HTML5 pushState history API under the hood 
>   (for example, React Router with browserHistory), many static file servers >will fail. For example, if you used React Router with a route for >/todos/42, >the development server will respond to localhost:3000/todos/42 
>   properly, but an Express serving a production build as above will not.
>
> This is because when there is a fresh page load for a /todos/42, the server >looks for the file build/todos/42 and does not find it. The server needs to >be configured to respond to a request to /todos/42 by serving index.html. >For example, we can amend our Express example above to serve index.html for >any unknown paths:

So I'm serving index.html for each unknown path requested by the browser.

Also - I've set the homepage propety in package.json to be ".".

The last thing I've tried adding -

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
```

to webpack.config.js

Note: I added logs to my app, and the value of  this.props.location in App.js
is always undefined (not sure if it's should be like that).

index.js (I'm not using redux yet in my app):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";

import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import targetsReducer from "./Reducers/targets-reducer";
import userReducer from "./Reducers/user-reducer";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const allReducers = combineReducers({
  targets: targetsReducer,
  user: userReducer
});

const store = createStore(
  allReducers,
  window.window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
    window.window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
// <Provider store={store}>
// </Provider>,

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

import Login from "./Components/Login";
import SidebarTest from "./Components/Sidebar";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import Campaigns from "./Components/Campaigns";
import Targets from "./Components/Targets";


class App extends Component {
  constructor(proprs) {
    super(proprs);
    this.state = {
      identifier: "",
      isLoggedIn: false
    };

    this.setIsLoggedIn = this.setIsLoggedIn.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("In App componentDidMount.");
    console.log("current path by window:", window.location.href);
    console.log("current path by react (props.location):", this.props.location);
    console.log("component state:", this.state);
  }

  /*Function that passed to Login component that toggles the isLoggedIn state*/
  setIsLoggedIn(identifier) {
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        identifier: identifier,
        isLoggedIn: !this.state.isLoggedIn
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("In App render.");
    console.log("current path by window:", window.location.href);
    console.log("current path by react (props.location):", this.props.location);
    console.log("component state:", this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="banner">
          <h1 id="banner-text">
            Uranus - Intelligence gathering and Attack system
          </h1>
        </div>
        {!this.state.isLoggedIn ? (
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            component={() => <Login setIsLoggedIn={this.setIsLoggedIn} />}
          />
        ) : (
          <div className="d-flex" id="page-container">
            <div className="sidebar-container">
              {this.state.isLoggedIn && <SidebarTest />}
            </div>
            <div className="navbar-and-data-container">
              <div className="navbar-container">
                {this.state.isLoggedIn && (
                  <Navbar identifier={this.state.identifier} />
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="data-container">
                <Switch>
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path="/Campaigns"
                    identifier={this.state.identifier}
                    component={Campaigns}
                  />
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path="/Targets/:campaignName"
                    component={Targets}
                  />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

For example:
if as a user i'm in "/" and i refresh the page, i dont have any problem and the screen displayed is the Login page.
But if I'm in "/campaigns" and then refresh the page, I expect the app to display the component registered to "/campaigns" but insted i get page with only the Banner defined in App.js

Another case, when I press a buttun that open a new window with the URL= 
"/Targets/:campaignName" again I expect to see the registered component to this URL defined in App.js file, insted i get page with only the Banner defined in App.js

Answer (score 0):

You are probably losing the state `isLoggedIn` when refreshing / opening a new tab.

You can check that by removing the ternary and see that the right component is rendered on refresh.

How would you persist the fact that a user is logged in? It's usually done with a session cookie.